# How to choose method to call depending on argument

Tags: javascript, typescript

#### The problem

I have a method `foo(msg: string, arg: string)` which will call a method from `bar`, which is an object in the same class as `foo`. Which method depends on the value of `arg`. My problem is how I should do that in a good way.

In my real code base, I want to use it for refactoring. Because it looks like this:

```
add() { foo('Adding', 'add'); }
sub() { foo('Subtracting', 'sub'); }
mul() { foo('Multiplying', 'mul'); }
div() { foo('Dividing', 'div'); }
```

#### My approach

I have a method like this:

```
foo(msg: string, arg: string) {
    console.log(msg);
    this.bar[arg]();
    // More code
}
```

In other words, I want to call the method `arg` from `bar`. And this works as it should. However, I would like to restrict the values that `arg` can have. I suppose I could do something like:

```
foo(arg: string) {
    if(arg !== 'fun1' && arg !== 'fun2') {
        // Handle error
    }

    this.bar[arg]();
}
```

The argument `arg` will never be "constructed". I use constant values directly all the time, like

```
foo('fun1');
```

and never something like

```
// Example of how I will NOT use this
let arg = someFunctionReturningAString();
foo(arg);
```

My concerns here are 1) safety and people saying "NOOOOO! That's bad practice!" and 2) that my IDE cannot detect spelling errors with my approach.

So my goal here is a convenient method to call a method from `bar` depending on the argument `arg`. Preferably something that makes an IDE capable of detecting spelling errors. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could use literal types in your signature, like:

```
foo(msg: string, arg: 'add' | 'sub' | 'mul' | 'div') {
    console.log(msg);
    this.bar[arg]();
    // More code
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html

Comment: Was it really this simple? :D

Comment: TypeScript is magic :)